gg_predict not plotting legend colours for confidence intervals correctly
I am building an interaction plot using ggpredict from the ggeffects package, but I am running into issues defining the colours of the legend based on the confidence intervals. Below is a reproducible example using the iris dataset.
library(ggeffects)

dat_iris <- iris

model_iris <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species + Petal.Width, data = dat_iris)

gg_iris <- plot(ggpredict(model_iris, terms=c("Sepal.Width", "Species", "Petal.Width")))

gg_iris +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF"))

This results in the following graph

Why is the legend not displaying the colours correctly? I can see the same problem in other threads using ggpredict (Drawing a regression line with interaction in ggplot2, How do I change color of graphs with ggPredict in R? plot(b, colors="bw")?, How to visualise an interaction effect using ggplot with method = glmmTMB::glmmTMB and point weights) but noone has commented on this or suggested how to fix it. If the only alternative is to manually build the graph, how can I do this?

"Why is the legend not displaying the colours correctly?" Can you be more explicit about what is wrong? Is dat_iris the same as iris? What package is ggpredict from?

Perhaps you are looking for + guides(color = guide_legend(), fill = guide_legend("Species")).

yes, dat_iris is the same as iris! I first called it as dat_iris <- iris ggpredict is from the ggeffects package but produces a ggplot object. I'll add this info to the question!

Is it also possible to edit the text of the legend using guides? If i add labs(colour = "New Legend") it adds a whole new legend. guides(color = guide_legend(), fill = guide_legend("Species", title = "New Legend")) throws an error

Use a named vector of colors, c(setosa="#190C3EFF", versicolor="#9C2964FF", virginica="#F8870EFF").

Why glm? With the default normal link lm is enough. In fact, there is no difference between the two.

@becbot "Species" is the title. You get two different guides if the title doesn't match. You would need to use guides(color = guide_legend("New Legend"), fill = guide_legend("New Legend"))

What is exactly wrong with the colors? I don't see any issues with the plot, or am I missing something? The threads you refer to a very old and it seems that issues have been fixed meanwhile. In your example, using plot(..., colors = "bw") will create a black-and-white plot. Furthermore, you can provide colors directly in the plot() method: plot(..., colors = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")).
